# I am trying to see if any value of one list matches any value of the other list, But I can't make it this way. Please help!..I don't understand why

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trynna make a code that checks whether a string value from a list is similar to other string value in another list..But this doesn't work, I am sure that the problem lies in the loop statement..But I can't figure it out..

```
import random as r

explc_words = ['f***','sh*t','dumb']

breakdown_list = ['Hello','myself','Rahul','sh*t','I','messed','up']

original = 'Hello, myself Rahul, Sh*t I messed up'

mindlang_words =['Please check again','Was it intentional?','please mind your language']

for j in explc_words:

    if j in breakdown_listi:

        print(r.choice(mindlang_words))
        break
    else:
        print("Please recheck everything you typed:", original)
        break
```

Comment: Your question was flagged by the SmokeDetector for foul language.  You don't need to use foul language to convey question clarity.  Just tell us that `one` and `two` are to be considered "foul" in the context of your question.  This way you don't need to obfuscate your words and your question is 100% clear.  If you don't like my edit, edit your question again, but without foul language.

Comment: I'm guessing your else should only happen once all of the words are checked, not after the first like you have it written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you aware you have a typo?
the variable "breakdown_listi" is not defined. You probably meant "breakdown_list".

After correcting this, I ran your code and got this:

```
Please recheck everything you typed: Hello, myself Rahul, Sh*t I messed up
```

I think the code you probably want is something like this:

```
if any(xw in breakdown_list for xw in explc_words):
    print(r.choice(midlang_words))
else:
    print("Please recheck everything you typed", original)
```

The issue is that for either condition you break the loop, so only the first word is getting tested.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it.